# Button won't execute further background color change using shared preferences

Tags: android, button, colors, sharedpreferences

my code changes the background color according to color value (ie `#FFFFFF` = White) typed into an edit text.

It does work, however it only accepts a single button click. I cannot change a 2nd (or 3rd etc.) time with a new color value.

My guess is perhaps the button needs a for loop applied to refresh the outcome according to each individual button click?

Why is this happening?

**MainActivity:**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    public Context context;
    EditText et;
    Button button;
    String color;
    String getColor;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.color);
        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("main", MODE_PRIVATE);

        if(getColor==null){
            getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        }else{
            getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(getColor));
            readLoginStatus();
        }
    }

    public void button(View view) {
        color = et.getText().toString();
        if(color.length()==7 && color.substring(0,1).equals("#")){
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(color));
            writeLoginStatus(true);
        }

    }


    public void writeLoginStatus(boolean status){
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("main", status);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public boolean readLoginStatus(){
        boolean status = false;
        status = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("main", false);
        return status;
    }

}
```

**activity_main.XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:id="@+id/color"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:hint="TYPE HERE YOUR COLOR"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:onClick="button"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.386" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` call in `public void button(View view) {}` method. Setting the view invalidates all previous findViewById and have to be called again.